# ADFS 2.0 SAMLRequest doesnt accept the request

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs2.0

Here is my service provider metadata
Here is my service provider metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor entityID="https://localhost:5200" validUntil="2022-08-30T19:10:29Z"
    xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:mdrpi="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:metadata:rpi"
    xmlns:mdattr="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:metadata:attribute"
    xmlns:mdui="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:metadata:ui"
    xmlns:idpdisc="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:profiles:SSO:idp-discovery-protocol"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <!-- insert ds:Signature element (omitted) -->
    <md:SPSSODescriptor  protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>MIID2TCCAsGgAwIBAgIUIAXntTTcs4IGVz8v8KpHAz46QfMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
            BQAwfDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxCzAJBgNVBAgMAkNBMRQwEgYDVQQHDAtZb3JiYSBM
            aW5kYTEWMBQGA1UECgwNTWluZExvZ2ljIElOQzEYMBYGA1UECwwPKi5taW5kbG9n
            aWMuYXBwMRgwFgYDVQQDDA8qLm1pbmRsb2dpYy5hcHAwHhcNMjEwODE3MTEyMDEw
            bvDj7E3wzI80gp7uU3KqU3UNswzsgcwSkwRTGS9sKkNnS62efQXKHRtR7fBwbOqU
            Y9bSXiTiSbd9zOvdVd+gGAqOqOB1o+jB55AvjtkzXhaoyBaQM1vStP7OCw0yFhNf
            fOKTM7EdAzTXoV4hJtUo0CMcUTFMP8PBnMHWQ5A6jZ8iBCXStcQ5Y71YhPUxa6dh
            I7rPk/j8+/qKbKyAhOSRvCiQY5xbAY12rW07WJ1JcWk7jvT7Kx4pll5Mh1G3lOcC
            AwEAAaNTMFEwHQYDVR0OBBYEFN2ugfhPaQ2Gyj/5aedoNN1eriDDMB8GA1UdIwQY
            MBaAFN2ugfhPaQ2Gyj/5aedoNN1eriDDMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZI
            hvcNAQELBQADggEBAAqn3aU/U7PA59yjHLjFb8LzMMoAS+b9Fu0d9JNym9K1ugzf
            dq/SgBS7MVrhz2bE/n3VQfnv+tjSLqQNwhyHmFy36Z43Q/BYrbofL6RSSrnozFz6
            uUYkuFFeCd857OyKOxKv33wD6EE6rNZqI7wEmKov2U7RNToxHD5NmeH0lTBHmBTH
            UWp/yLQkTlMZYUDfOCBxlF2+bGS1hzdXPOELN3RZNRk9M61NHyISfE7VpqIlI1Ro
            x4DUK89TKDG/mLl985h+sTuPMmIMpl1ozXrJWhKucoqjSfMTh/MLQTQS1lHmeAFH
            npro/M9yy1Uwrz4K93nju5kNLLZL7NRzddjHOYs=</ds:X509Certificate>
          </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </md:KeyDescriptor>
      <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
      <md:AssertionConsumerService index="0" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localhost:5200/map"/>
      <md:AttributeConsumingService index="0">
        <md:ServiceName xml:lang="en">Example.com Employee Portal</md:ServiceName>
        <md:RequestedAttribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="E-Mail Address"/>
        <md:RequestedAttribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="Name"/>
      </md:AttributeConsumingService>
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
    <md:Organization>
      <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">Localtest.com Inc.</md:OrganizationName>
      <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">Localtest.com</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
      <md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="en">https://localhos:5200/</md:OrganizationURL>
    </md:Organization>
  </md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Here is my SERVICE PROVIDER initiative request

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="id-16f33a7e-4381-4d40-9fdd-1949dd679e86" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-09-09T07:58:45Z " Destination="https://saml.mlads.mindlogic.app/adfs/ls/" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"> <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://localhost:5200</Issuer> <samlp:NameIDPolicy Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"/> <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext> <samlp:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</samlp:AuthnContextClassRef> </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext> </samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

I deflated and encoded base 64 but my adfs server throws error

## deflated data

nZJtS8MwEMe/Ssj7NunWPTR0g7EhDFTGFF/4LiSpC+Sh5lKc39600zGQDRECgf/l/ve7u9TArWnZqosHt1fvnYKIjtY4YENggbvgmOeggTluFbAo2NPq4Z6Ncsra4KMX3mC03SywllkxbcZjPlNZOZ4XWSlLmlWNTHpVVlJOZ5WaTzF6UQG0dwucPFIqQKe2DiJ3MUl0VGS0SueZzthkzsrJK8Jok7i043FIO8TYAiOkJ8yt4RJyq500/k2LnLct4bIBYoBgtPYOVO97rY0iLwYlwTc+WB6ZslyblZRBAeAlqge+cBrK7XFwABV6RLz8QTRecHPwENlkRGlNTmbJ9TT2x+Sx3ey80eIT3Q31/41Kzq7fe1Ry2GoaQVTHeI5eimuTmPeq+fvKL3q8+Uww0XsneZeuDx9kTa7XT3DkNjv5/U+XXw==

Error details: Found invalid data while decoding.

Note: I am triggering the url from browser
https://saml.mlads.mindlogic.app/adfs/ls?SAMLRequest=nZJtS8MwEMe/Ssj7NunWPTR0g7EhDFTGFF/4LiSpC+Sh5lKc39600zGQDRECgf/l/ve7u9TArWnZqosHt1fvnYKIjtY4YENggbvgmOeggTluFbAo2NPq4Z6Ncsra4KMX3mC03SywllkxbcZjPlNZOZ4XWSlLmlWNTHpVVlJOZ5WaTzF6UQG0dwucPFIqQKe2DiJ3MUl0VGS0SueZzthkzsrJK8Jok7i043FIO8TYAiOkJ8yt4RJyq500/k2LnLct4bIBYoBgtPYOVO97rY0iLwYlwTc+WB6ZslyblZRBAeAlqge+cBrK7XFwABV6RLz8QTRecHPwENlkRGlNTmbJ9TT2x+Sx3ey80eIT3Q31/41Kzq7fe1Ry2GoaQVTHeI5eimuTmPeq+fvKL3q8+Uww0XsneZeuDx9kTa7XT3DkNjv5/U+XXw==

## ADFS error Log

Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data
Protocol Name:
Relying Party:

```
Exception details: 
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Found invalid data while decoding.
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.DecodeDynamicBlockHeader()
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Decode()
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(Byte[] bytes, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.DeflateCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.DecodeMessageInternal(String message)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.ReadProtocolMessage(String encodedSamlMessage)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlBindingSerializer.CreateFromNameValueCollection(Uri baseUrl, NameValueCollection collection)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpRedirectSamlBindingSerializer.ReadMessage(Uri requestUrl, NameValueCollection form)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlMessageFactory.CreateMessage(WrappedHttpListenerRequest httpRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlContextFactory.CreateProtocolContextFromRequest(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.CreateProtocolContext(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.GetProtocolHandler(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler& protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)`
```

Comment: In Service provider metadata right?@AkshayGaonkar

Comment: Both Service Provider Metadata and Service Provider initiated request are invalid. Use [Validate XML with the XSD schema](https://www.samltool.com/validate_xml.php) to validate the metadata. Use [Validate SAML AuthN Request](https://www.samltool.com/validate_authn_req.php) to validate the  Service Provider initiated request

Comment: I have validated both metadata and authn request but still same issue i am facing @AkshayGaonkar

Comment: Now the edited XML in the post are valid. Can you give some more info on the error details?

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar I have added addtional logs from adfs

Comment: Check if the deflated and encoded string can be decoded and inflated. Use [Base64 Decode + Inflate](https://www.samltool.com/decode.php) to validate. You can also try by just encoding the authentication request without deflating it and give it a try

Comment: yes i can able to Base64 Decode + inflate i am able to getback same data. is sigAlg& signature is mandatory parameter along with SAMLRequest parameter @AkshayGaonkar

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to encode url after I encode url it works.so the request should be = urlencode(base64encode(deflate))